# Letting Django superuser define new badges in gamification component

Tags: django, django-admin, badge

We are implementing the gamification component of a project in Django. We would like the superuser to be able to define new badges and redefine existing ones inside the Django admin interface.

The problem as we see it is that defining the sometimes complicated conditions for badges needs to be done in code. The superuser will be technically knowledgeable, but will not be a programmer.

How would you go about letting the superuser do this in the Django admin interface, rather than alter the application?

Here are some examples of badges:

- Created 10 tags that have been used on 10 questions by 10 different
  members.
- Answered 10 unanswered questions.
- Wrote 20 comments to a question (comments got at least 5 points each).

Comment: You're asking a non programmer to do programming work? Is there a reason you can't have a programmer add the badges?

Comment: After the development ends, our website is supposed to be handed over to a 'superuser' who takes care of future maintenance. According to the design, he/she'll probably needs to tinker various aspects of the site, including requirements for getting badges, creating new badges, etc., to keep the site balanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say if you expect the superuser to be a programmer or not.

If you can assume this then you could include Python code in a database field and use `eval` or `exec` to run it.

For example:

```
badge.function = """
def award_badge(user):
    return False
"""

vars = {}
exec(badge.function, vars)

if vars["award_badge"](user):
    ...
```

Clearly this has a lot of scope for abuse or mistakes, and certainly wouldn't be suitable if you expect non-technical users to be creating badges.

Depending on the complexity of the rules you need to create you might be able to create rules engine for executing them. In this case you create a sort of mini-language where each step in the process of deciding whether to award a badge or not is specified by a row in the database. Rules engines are a complicated topic so I won't go into detail here.

You're probably better off hard coding the rules for badges in your code than using either of these suggestions.